# Is it possible to merge multiple email threads in Apple's Mail client?

Tags: mail.app, email

Is there some way to edit some part of email messages so that Mail (the Apple application on iOS and macOS) considers them one conversation?

Is there a particular email header that Apple's Mail is using to decide "these messages are a thread"?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, only the [Hey](https://www.hey.com/features/merge-threads/) and [Missive](https://missiveapp.com/features) email services support this feature.